# Trying to make a 3 columns grid with gutter with pure CSS Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, margin

I am dealing with a stack here..

I am building a website that has 100% width and changes to 90% when reaches 768px. The section with 6 images (2 rows with 3 images each is not working as I wished. The images have no margins until they reach 768px, above this size I want to apply 5 or 10px of margin around the images, but keeping them in 3 columns. I thought that using border-box as my box-sizing property would protect me against the images wrapping to the next line, but that is not what happened. I tried to apply a negative margin to the images wrapper, but that is not working either. Would you help me to find a solution for that problem?

PS: The code works exactly as I want when it reaches 1320px aftera max-width to the images (code applied on media query min-width 992px). It is precise and has exactly the same width/margin as the guide div that I made.

I need this as final result, in a way it is fully responsive and fluid (working with % because new images will be maybe included and this equal margins must be kept, no matter the size of the viewport is):

[image]

Thank you!

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <title>RESTAURANT</title>

    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />

    <!--     Favicon     -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href=""/>

    <!--     Fonts Google    -->

        <!-- 1. Poppins -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,400i,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- 2. Herr Von Muellerhoff -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Herr+Von+Muellerhoff" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- 3. Open Sans -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Font-awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" />


    <!-- CSS Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-mqueries.css"><!--media queries-->
</head>

<body>
<div class="site-container">

<header class="grey4-bg flex-center section-sep">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>

<main>
    <section class="services section-sep">
        <div class="marged">

        <div class="section-header">
            <h2 class="handwriting">Services</h2>
            <h3>super class service</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae fugit labore delectus.</p>
        </div>

            <div class="images-parent neg-margin flex">
                <div class="img-holder bg-img"></div>
                <div class="img-holder bg-img"></div>
                <div class="img-holder bg-img"></div>

                <div class="img-holder bg-img"></div>
                <div class="img-holder bg-img"></div>
                <div class="img-holder bg-img"></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.marged -->
    </section><!-- /.services -->
</main>

<section class="guide">
    <div class="marged pad-v10 blue-bg txt-center white-txt">guide</div>
</section>


</div><!-- /.site-container -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";

*{margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;}

body{height:100%; color:#292929;}
html{height:100%; font-size:16px; box-sizing:border-box;}
*, *:before, *:after{box-sizing:border-box;}
ul{list-style: none;}
a{color:inherit;text-decoration: none;}
p{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}

/* POSITIONING ELEMENTS */
/* Flex, Margin, Padding */

.flex, .flex-col, .justify-c, .flex-align-c, .flex-center, .flex-col-center {display: flex; }

.txt-center{text-align: center;}

/* COLORS and SHADOWS*/


.white-bg{ background-color: #fff; } .white-txt{ color: #fff; }
.grey4-bg{background-color:#f1f4f9;} .grey4-txt{color:#f1f4f9;}
.blue-bg{ background-color: #3F72AF; } .blue-txt{ color: #3F72AF; }


/* OTHER */

.bg-img{background-size:cover; background-position:center center; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.hidden-sm{display:none;}
.visible-md{display:none;}
.visible-lg{display:none;}


/* WEBSITE STYLE */ 
/* GENERAL */
/* MATERIAL KIT - ELEMENTS */


.section-sep{padding: 20px 0;  }
.marged{max-width:1170px; margin:0 auto;}


.section-header{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding:bottom:20px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.section-header h2{
    margin-bottom:-25px;
    color:#e7e7e7;
    font-size:60px;
    font-family: 'Herr Von Muellerhoff', cursive;
    font-weight:400;
    line-height:1em;
}

.section-header h3{
    color:#474747;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    font-size:;
    font-weight:700;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

.section-header p{
    color:#8d8d8d;
    max-width:446px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px 0;
    line-height:1em;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:300;
}


.btn{
    min-width:200px;
    padding:20px 0;
    background-color:#606060;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/******************************************************

*********************** HEADER  ***********************

*******************************************************/



h1 {
  font-size: 55px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#ee0979 0%, #ff5c3b 30%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#ee0979 0%, #ff5c3b 30%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}


/******************************************************

***********************  MAIN  ************************

*******************************************************/


/* SECTION : SERVICES */


.services .flex{
    justify-content:center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}


.neg-margin{
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}

.services .images-parent{
    padding-top:30px;
    background-color:pink;
}

.services .img-holder{
    background-image:url("https://images6.alphacoders.com/434/434430.jpg");
    width:33.33%;
    height:100px;
    max-height:300px;
}
```

Media queries

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) { 

    .services .img-holder{
        height:150px;
    }

  }

/* MD - MEDIUM */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { 

    .marged{
        width:90%;
    }

    .services .img-holder{
        margin:5px;
    }
 }

/* LG - LARGE */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) { 
    .neg-margin{
        margin-left:-15px;
        margin-right:-15px;
    }

    .services .img-holder{
        height:300px;
        max-width:370px;
        margin:15px;
    }
 }
```

Comment: not clear what you are looking for....?...also no need to post all the code...try to make a simple working snippet here so that it will be easy for us to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

**Is this you want ??**

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body {
 height: 100%;
 color: #292929;
}
html {
 height: 100%;
 font-size: 16px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
 list-style: none;
}
a {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}
p {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
/* POSITIONING ELEMENTS */
/* Flex, Margin, Padding */

.flex, .flex-col, .justify-c, .flex-align-c, .flex-center, .flex-col-center {
 display: flex;
}
.txt-center {
 text-align: center;
}
/* COLORS and SHADOWS*/


.white-bg {
 background-color: #fff;
}
.white-txt {
 color: #fff;
}
.grey4-bg {
 background-color: #f1f4f9;
}
.grey4-txt {
 color: #f1f4f9;
}
.blue-bg {
 background-color: #3F72AF;
}
.blue-txt {
 color: #3F72AF;
}
/* OTHER */

.bg-img {
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.hidden-sm {
 display: none;
}
.visible-md {
 display: none;
}
.visible-lg {
 display: none;
}
/* WEBSITE STYLE */ 
/* GENERAL */
/* MATERIAL KIT - ELEMENTS */


.section-sep {
 padding: 20px 0;
}
.marged {
 max-width: 1170px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.section-header {
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding:bottom:20px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}
.section-header h2 {
 margin-bottom: -25px;
 color: #e7e7e7;
 font-size: 60px;
 font-family: 'Herr Von Muellerhoff', cursive;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 1em;
}
.section-header h3 {
 color: #474747;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 line-height: 1.2em;
 font-size:;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.section-header p {
 color: #8d8d8d;
 max-width: 446px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 10px 0;
 line-height: 1em;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 300;
}
.btn {
 min-width: 200px;
 padding: 20px 0;
 background-color: #606060;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
}
/******************************************************

*********************** HEADER  ***********************

*******************************************************/



h1 {
 font-size: 55px;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ee0979 0%, #ff5c3b 30%);
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #ee0979 0%, #ff5c3b 30%);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
/******************************************************

***********************  MAIN  ************************

*******************************************************/


/* SECTION : SERVICES */


.services .flex {
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.neg-margin {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
}
.services .images-parent {
 padding-top: 30px;
 background-color: pink;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
}
.services .img-holder {
 background-image: url("https://images6.alphacoders.com/434/434430.jpg");
 width: 33.33%;
 height: 100px;
 max-height: 300px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
 .services .img-holder {
  height: 150px;
 }
}

/* MD - MEDIUM */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .marged {
  width: 90%;
 }
 .services .img-holder {
  margin: 5px;
 }
}

/* LG - LARGE */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
 .neg-margin {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
 }
 .services .img-holder {
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 370px;
  margin: 13px 0;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .services .img-holder {
    width: 32%;
     margin: 6px 0 !important;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<title>RESTAURANT</title>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />

<!--     Favicon     -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href=""/>

<!--     Fonts Google    -->

<!-- 1. Poppins -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,400i,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- 2. Herr Von Muellerhoff -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Herr+Von+Muellerhoff" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- 3. Open Sans -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Font-awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<!-- CSS Style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-mqueries.css">
<!--media queries-->
</head>

<body>
<div class="site-container">
    <header class="grey4-bg flex-center section-sep">
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="services section-sep">
            <div class="marged">
                <div class="section-header">
                    <h2 class="handwriting">Services</h2>
                    <h3>super class service</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae fugit labore delectus.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="images-parent neg-margin flex">
                    <div class="img-holder bg-img"></div>
                    <div class="img-holder bg-img"></div>
                    <div class="img-holder bg-img"></div>
                    <div class="img-holder bg-img"></div>
                    <div class="img-holder bg-img"></div>
                    <div class="img-holder bg-img"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.marged --> 
        </section>
        <!-- /.services --> 
    </main>
    <section class="guide">
        <div class="marged pad-v10 blue-bg txt-center white-txt">guide</div>
    </section>
</div>
<!-- /.site-container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Anzil, I need a space between the images (a gutter) that is equal at the sides and to the next row. But, the entire grid must be aligned with the guide below it in terms of width.

Comment: Hi Anzil, this is almost. I need the images to be aligned with the "blue-guide". The images on the left have to "touch" the end of the pink background (so we will not see this pink background anymore) and the same needs to happen with the right side.. The section must be fluid, the vertical and horizontal margins of the grid must be always equal

Comment: @Jorge , I updated my answer please check once more ;)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Anzil. Unfortunatelly this code you suggested is not 100% responsive and fluid. It doesn't work for every size of viewport. What I am trying to understand is why the 33.33% of width is not being respected in a border-box box sizing place, after we apply margins. Thanks for your effort to help.